# Make better resolution desktop icon via java web start on windows

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application, java-web-start, jnlp

I have set it up so that running my java web start application creates a desktop icon. On Linux this icon is beautiful, just as I designed it including transparency. On Windows however ( tested on 7 and 8 ), the image is down-scaled, blocky and without transparency.

Is there a way to increase the resolution of the icon made via java webstart?

Answer (score 0):

Java webstart has this problem that lowers the resolution of your icon if the dimension of your icon is missing in the jnlp file. Make sure you specify the actual width and height of your image like this:

```
<icon href="icon.png" width="64" height="64"/>
```